# How to accept one of two configurations of predicate arguments

Tags: prolog

Say i have two variables A and B, and two predicates firstPred() and secondPred()

I'm trying to express something along the lines of:

```
(firstPred(A) && secondPred(B)) || (firstPred(B) && secondPred(A))
```

I currently have

```
firstPred(A),
secondPred(B).
```

but this only covers the first case. How can i add support for the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to predicates in Prolog use the notation `Name/Arity`, where `Arity` is the number of arguments. Therefore, instead of writing `firstPred()` and `secondPred()`, write instead `firstPred/1` and `secondPred/1`. Better yet, following Prolog coding guidelines, use underscores instead of CamelCase when naming predicate.

To answer your question, you need to define a predicate to check your condition. This predicate will take two arguments. A direct translation of your condition would be:

```
condition(A, B) :-
    (   first_predicate(A),
        second_predicate(B)
    ;   first_predicate(B),
        second_predicate(A)
    ).
```

But this is not considered good style and it's preferable to use instead two clauses:

```
condition(A, B) :-
    first_predicate(A),
    second_predicate(B)
condition(A, B) :-
    first_predicate(B),
    second_predicate(A).
```

Note that this solution assumes that the disjunction in the condition is not an exclusive disjunction. Is that the case?

Comment: Perhaps you could define **disjunction** and **exclusive disjunction** in this context?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks. You were correct in assuming that it is not an exclusive disjunction.